# How to convert some long double to long int in c?

Tags: c, casting, int, double

I'm trying to convert a double type variable to a long long int. The only way I know to do it is by casting. Althoulg it seems ok, I'm not receiving the number I wanted.

I post the code piece bellow:

```
double fator = 100000000;
long long int iLongitude = (long long int)(fLongitude*10000000);
```

The number I expected was -4396478167 and I'm getting -439647816, without the last digit.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `fLongitude` and its value?

Comment: const double fLongitude = -43.96478166666666....

Comment: `double int` is not valid.

Comment: ok, ignore double int, in fact the code is just double fator

Comment: Take a look at http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Somebody is not too good at counting zeroes.

Comment: What if you won't write int (10000000), but make so: `long long int iLongitude = (long long int)(fLongitude*fator);`?

Comment: Ok, It seems I have the answer. The problem don't seems to be in the convertion but in how I'm showing this. I was trying to show by printf("Number %d", iLongitude) and getting the wrong number. When I change it to printf("Number: %10f\n", (double)iLongitude), I can see what I wanted but in double format. Although it's not what I expected, it seems to show that the convertion was ok.

Comment: Ok, I admit I made some mistakes when I posted it. I'm not counting zeros wrong and fator was unncessary too. Sorry, but the problem wasn't there, It was what I comment before, printf can't print what such so long int number.

Comment: Read `man 3 printf`: it says you should use "%lld" for long long.

Comment: does anybody know any other way to print the value?

Comment: Thank you Eddy_Em, I put it with %lld and now its ok!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just need to add one more zero, and also round:

```
(long long int)(fLongitude*100000000 + 0.5);
```

Since casting truncates results, the `+ 0.5` will round up if the fractional part is larger than `0.5`.